# Moving along columns in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create this function using this data:

```
df<-read.table(text="x    y
0    1000
0    1000
4    1000
2    1000
10   1000
5    1000",header=T)
```

The aim is to get the cumulative difference for both columns x and y. Currently I get the values for x with an error:

> 1: In mrowdiff[i] <- df[i + 1, ] - df[i, ] :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I'm thinking this has to do with not subsetting the second column. I've tried to make it work but sadly failed:

```
rowdiff<-function(df,na.rm=F){
  mrowdiff<-numeric(nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:nrow(df))

    {
   mrowdiff[i]<-df[i+1,]-df[i,]
   if(na.rm==T){
     mrowdiff<- mrowdiff[!is.na(mrowdiff)]
  }

  }
do.call(rbind,mrowdiff)
}
```

Current Output:
rowdiff(df,na.rm = T)

```
    [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    4
[3,]   -2
[4,]    8
[5,]   -5
```

I expect a second column with 0s.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your ultimate goal here (it's a little unclear), but have you considered the `diff()` function?

Comment: You may have to consider the case when  it is greater than the number of rows `i + 1`

Comment: I'm looking to write my own function for learning purposes. I'm therefore avoiding base or package based solutions. The goal is to get the "cumulative difference".

Comment: What is the expected output for this example?

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some changes you can make. Below is the complete function:

```
rowdiff<-function(df,na.rm=F){
> mrowdiff <- df # you want mrowdiff to have the same basic structure as df, so start with making it equal to df (there are more efficient ways to do this)
> for(i in 1:nrow(df))
+ {
+     mrowdiff[i, ]<-df[i+1, ]-df[i, ] # calculate differences for both rows at once
+     }
> mrowdiff<- na.omit(mrowdiff) # remove missing values
> mrowdiff # there's nothing to rbind, since you've been working with a dataframe all along
  }

rowdiff(df)
   x y
1  0 0
2  4 0
3 -2 0
4  8 0
5 -5 0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work or I'm misinterpreting it. Could you post the full function?

Comment: I added the full function, starting with a clean workspace. What seems off to you? Maybe I misinterpreted the question?

Comment: Your suggested edits were great, but I wasn't totally sure how to make them take effect, so I made them manually.

Comment: No worries. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach that avoids using a function, although you mentioned that...

```
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    df[,paste0("rowdiff",j)] <- NA
    for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
        df[i,paste0("rowdiff",j)] <- df[i,j] - df[i-1,j]
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
> df
   x    y rowdiff1 rowdiff2
1  0 1000       NA       NA
2  0 1000        0        0
3  4 1000        4        0
4  2 1000       -2        0
5 10 1000        8        0
6  5 1000       -5        0
```